# communication between C# async sockets and C++ winsock2

Tags: c#, c++, sockets

I am trying to use the function of sendfile C# async socket (as a server) and get this file received at C++ native code client.
As I use this to update files at client from my C# server, can't use webServices because of requirements.
This I am using to send file

```
IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress  ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);

// Create a TCP socket.
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

// Connect the socket to the remote endpoint.
client.Connect(ipEndPoint);

// There is a text file test.txt located in the root directory.
string fileName = "C:\\test.txt";

// Send file fileName to remote device
Console.WriteLine("Sending {0} to the host.", fileName);
client.SendFile(fileName);

// Release the socket.
client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
client.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

And...what exactly is your question?

I'm not too strong with c#, but on c++, you either instantiate a thread, which perpetually listens with select for incoming data (making it 'Async' too) and then process it either in a synchronized method (use a CriticalSection if necessary).

Just to clarify this, this is the general working method of a server/client communication.

Server:
Instantiates Socket, binds itself to port and listens for incoming connections.
When connection comes in, performs handshake and adds the new client to a collection of clients.
Responds to incoming requests/sends out periodic updates to all clients

Client:
Instantiates socket, uses 'connect' to connect to the server and starts to communicate according to protocol.

Edit: Just to make sure, this isn't a trivial problem of miscommunication, do you mean how to SAVE the file at the client?

You may want to use this code: (Assuming you're using select in a thread)

```
fd_set fds;             //Watchlist for Sockets
int RecvBytes;
char buf[1024];
FILE *fp = fopen("FileGoesHere", "wb");
while(true) {
    FD_ZERO(&fds);      //Reinitializes the Watchlist
    FD_SET(sock, &fds); //Adds the connected socket to the watchlist
    select(sock + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);    //Blocks, until traffic is detected
    //Only one socket is in the list, so checking with 'FD_ISSET' is unnecessary
    RecvBytes = recv(sock, buf, 1024, 0);  //Receives up to 1024 Bytes into 'buf'
    if(RecvBytes == 0) break;   //Connection severed, ending the loop.
    fwrite(buf, RecvBytes, fp); //Writes the received bytes into a file
}
fclose(fp);                     //Closes the file, transmission complete.
```

Comment: We have a function in managed C# code to send complete file by using sockets,

Comment: You may want to check the edited code. Did this code snippet answer your question?
Or do you want to know, how to make a client socket under C?

Comment: no , I just wanted to know that how the C++ client code will work against the server code of C# with a built in function of sendfile

Comment: Ah, now THAT's a question I can answer. And the answer is a definite 'Yes'. You see, whatever goes over the wire is nothing but 1s and 0s. There's no difference between C# Bits and C++ Bits. You just need to take care of a potential Endianess problem, which you shouldn't have with this scenario.

Regarding the how: I already gave you a piece of code, how it can work. Or do you have a special scenario in mind?